# window.onload include images

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Does `window.onlaod` include image load? or I must use another event for it?

I want use ajax call to get HTML document which contains images, but I want show this document when all images are loaded.

Comment: `window.onload` waits for images. That's why jQuery jumps through the loops to provide you the `ready` event

Comment: Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520780/when-is-window-onload-fired

Comment: @JanDvorak; It means jQuery ready waits for images???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window.onload vs document.ready ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Comment: @TaronPro jQuery ready does not wait for images, and makes a lot of effort not to.

Comment: @TaronPro No. He's saying that jQuery (and most other frameworks) endeavor to provide developers with an "onReady" event that fires when DOM is ready -- which is quite different from when the images are loaded. Javascript needs the DOM, it doesn't need the images.

Comment: Am I the only one here to see that the OP is talking about an ajax call?

Comment: Yes, i talking about ajax call)))

Comment: I'm post another question for this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840703/when-is-triggered-ajax-success/14840751#14840751

Comment: @TaronPro maybe you should just delete this one then, as apparently people got confused.

Comment: I can't delete this question, there was message "Sorry you can't delete question that has answers"

Comment: @Christophe I dont get normal answer for my question not for this not for that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it does include all webpage's resource's load - more information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.onload

Comment: The OP was talking about doing *something*, the real meat of his question is about doing something when the images have loaded. That it is an AJAX call is not significant. I see his other question, which clarifies matters somewhat, but this answer addresses the details given in the question, no need for -1.

Comment: @Chris of course the fact that it is ajax is significant. The question is about window.onload which will be triggered before the images coming through ajax are loaded.

Comment: `window.onload` is not related to AJAX. Now that there's a second (bad) question with more details, it is more clear what the OP is after. In **THIS** question, he asks about sending an AJAX request after "the images" are loaded. He could be asking about changing the font color after "the images" are loaded, about replacing the document content, or firing an AJAX request, it doesn't really matter -- the question is about waiting for "the images" to load and then doing something. The downvote here is uncalled for, the problem is the wording of the question (and making a duplicate).

Comment: @Chris please read the question carefully, we are talking about **all** images (not "the images"), including the images contained in a document loaded via ajax.

Comment: Again (and for the last time -- honestly, who cares?), this question does not make that entirely clear. The OP could have (and should have) simply edited this question to improve the wording instead of making a new one.

That aside, I read this question and reach the same conclusion this answer did -- the OP is asking about order of DOM events. He says "Does window.onlaod include image load", and the answer is "yes". The OP doesn't have to accept the answer, but it doesn't deserve a downvote *in my opinion*. The end.

Comment: honestly, who cares? => well, I just wish people read the whole question, not just the first sentence.

Comment: @Chris btw point taken, but unfortunately too late to remove my downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, in short it waits for whole visual content to come together, it will trigger after the completion of the load of all the images, all the frames and their contents.