# when is triggered AJAX success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want load some HTML document by AJAX, but I want to show it when all images in this document are loded.

```
$('.about').click(function () {
    $(".back").load('Tour.html', function () {
        $(".back").show();
    });
});
```

".back" should be visible when all images in Tour.html are loaded, when is triggered a success event??

Comment: What is ".black"? Loading a whole page in another document doesn't look right, usually you'll want to select a fragment.

Comment: ".back" is DIV element, i load part of html document in this DIV

Comment: well, your code shows that you're loading a whole document, not just a part of it.

Comment: no I'm just wrote Tour.html as test path, really it is ASP.NET MVC action)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".back").load('Tour.html', function (html) {
    var $imgs = $(html).find('img');
    var len = $imgs.length, loaded = 0;
    $imgs.one('load', function() {
        loaded++;
        if (loaded == len) {
            $(".back").show();
        }
    })
    .each(function () { if (this.complete) { $(this).trigger('load'); });
});
```

This requires at least one `<img>` in the returned html.

Comment: what about if my images are background-image for div elements??)

Comment: @TaronPro you can't attach load handlers to that, so you can either find all divs with background images and create image elements to attach load handlers to instead, OR (perhaps more easily) you can just emit hidden versions of all the background images along with the rest of your html

Comment: mmm... this code seems to imply that images only start loading after the whole Tour.html has been loaded (html, styles and scripts). Isn't there a race condition here?

Comment: @Christophe I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  What would go wrong?

Comment: It could mean that some images are already loaded when you set loaded to 0. Honestly I don't know, I am just trying to understand how $().load works.

Comment: @Christophe you are absolutely correct, but that problem is handled in the `.each` callback.

Comment: Got it, thanks! So you could reverse the logic and test for complete first.

Comment: @Christophe the order of the bindings does not affect execution order

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest is to use an iframe instead. Here is some sample code in plain JavaScript:

```
var ifr=document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.style.display="none";
document.body.appendChild(ifr);
ifr.onload=function() {
    // Do what you want with Tour.html loaded in the iframe
};
ifr.src="Tour.html";
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe, but i did it a very different way, in answers reports do not

Answer (score 0):

[ImagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) is what you are looking for.

Place all code (ajax request in this case), when the images specified are loaded.

The plugin specifies why you cannot use `load()` on cached images