# document.ready() doesn't work but setinterval() does

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't really know why. I have a page with lots of things that load external things.

**E.g** I have an slider that loads images with a script at the bottom of the page... I have another script tag at the bottom of it with some animations and stuff of kindness being applied to that slider.

The problem is that I tried to use a `document.ready()`, but it doesn't work... So I thought it was because the document is ready but the slider isn't, or something like that.

So, I put the same things I was executing in the `document.ready()` into a `setInterval()` refreshing every  second... It worked, but the problem is that, even when I get what I want with that script, it keep refreshing!!! And I don't want it, what I want is it to execute only once, but only when the page is really ready (When the refreshing animation in the tab of the browser stops) How can I do that? Some idea?

Comment: Show the code, that will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `window.onload = yourInitialisesFunction;`
the onload event fireds when your DOM is completly loaded.

(Sorry it was window.onload = yourFunction), JQueries ready() function fires when the DOM is parsed but not if all images etc is loaded.

Comment: Even if it has to load external things to it? because it executes what I put there, but the tab keeps with the load animation...

Comment: yes it should work with external resources too, when the browser has finished rendering then this handler should be activated. Also answered in this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520780/when-is-window-onload-fired hope this helps.

Comment: But if your tab has an own internal loading routine which prepares something in javascript, this cant be know by the browser. The browser just tells you when every resource is loaded and ready to use.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing jquery's ready method with native onload.

Either use:

```
window.onload = function(){
  // do something here. Everything including resources are loaded
}
```

or:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // do something here. The DOM is loaded
});
```