# JavaScript - How to take variable that defined inside onload function outside?

Tags: javascript

I want to get all input element in html page. I've tried this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
}
```

But, when I check it with alert function outside `onload`, it doesn't do anything

```
alert(input.length) // doesn't do anything
```

If I use this, this will give me the numbers of input element in html page.

```
window.onload = function(){
    input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    alert(input.length);
}
```

And that's mean I can't access it outside. How can I access it outside?

**UPDATE**

This is how the html page looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="actions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="name" /><br/>
    <label for="address">Address:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="address" /><br/>
    <label for="email">E-mail:</label><br/>
    <input type="text" id="email" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're making a global variable because you're not declaring it with `var`, so you **can** access it outside the function. You'll have to post more code in order for anybody to tell what's going wrong. (If `alert(input.length)` really does not do *anything* then there's an error and you should check your developer console.)

Comment: *When* are you checking it outside `onload`? You may simply be checking too early, before `onload` has actually been called.

Comment: Actually, that's all my code. I just testing it and wondering how to make it works.

Comment: Well, thats probably because the alert-function is aleady called, before the window.onload-event is fired. But i can't figure why theres no error shown..

Comment: I put `alert(input.length)` right below `onload` function (in first example). So, the `alert` function is called first?

Comment: [when is window.onload fired?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520780/when-is-window-onload-fired)

Comment: Yes - you're telling the browser what to do *when* the window is fully loaded. That will happen later. Then you tell it to call `alert()`, *right now*.

Comment: Yes it is called first. The function you added behind the onload event is called after everything is loaded. The alert-function is just called, the moment the browser parsed it.

Answer (score 6):

There are a couple ways of doing it.

### The Dangerous Way

```
var input; // Input declared outside
window.onload = function(){
    input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
}
// Sometime later...
alert(input.length);
```

This assumes that `Sometime later...` magically happens after `window.onload` was fired, which may or may not be the case, you have no guarantee.

### The Hacky Way

You can make sure all of your `<script>` elements are found at the bottom of your page. This eliminates the need for `window.onload`, but as I said, it's hacky. Order of inclusion shouldn't matter.

### The Promised Way

With ES6 (or with a library like [bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)), you have Promises! So you can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Returns a promise the resolves when window fires the load event
 */
function onload() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // Resolve if window is already loaded by the time this is called.
        if (document.readyState === 'complete') { return resolve(); }
        // If reached here, window not loaded. Resolve when it is.
        window.addEventListener('load', resolve);
    }
}
```

Then you can call...

```
var inputAvailable = onload().then(function() {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
    return input;
});
// inputAvailable is a Promise object that resolves once querySelectorAll()
// is executed and the result returned. It resolves with the returned value.
```

And somewhere else...

```
// The handler passed to .then will be called once inputAvailable resolves.
// Which is always after querySelectorAll() was executed.
inputAvailable.then(function(inputs) {
    alert(inputs.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Reference your script tags at the bottom of the HTML page and not in the head.  This will remove any ambiguity as to whether the page has been loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
    input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
    alert(input.length);
}
```

Now you should be able to extract the code from "window.load()" and get the expected results.

```
input = document.querySelectorAll("input");
alert(input.length);
```

Comment: While that definitely works, it's somewhat hacky. You can't always control the order of inclusion either.

Comment: which part is hacky?  if you're referring to my comment about the position of the script tags, referencing them at the bottom of the page is considered a best practice these days.  placing them at the bottom always forces them to be loaded last.

Comment: No, it's not. The position of where I put my `<script>` elements shouldn't matter one bit.

Comment: ... My point is that if you write your JavaScript and DOM correctly, the place where you put your script doesn't matter. "Always put your script at the bottom" is a faux best practice for those who don't know how to correctly utilize events. The *only* thing that always putting your scripts at the bottom does, is save you one level of indentation. Not good enough reason to call it an absolute best practice IMO.

Comment: it was originally considered a best practice because it ensured 2 things  1) that the DOM was completely loaded prior to referencing any objects and 2) for loading performance

Comment: that being said, i completely agree with you.  if you wanted to ensure that no matter where your scripts are loaded that they ran correctly, your solution is key.