# Why my function not alert when load page [javascript]?

Tags: javascript

Why my function not alert when load page [javascript]?

When scroll page it's alert work good.

When resize page it's alert work good.

But when load page why not alert ?

How can i do that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/af2kgoxu/

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll load resize', function () {
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you are wrapping your `scroll`,`load`, `resize` operations in `$(window).load(function(){});` when you can directly call it. Change your snippet as below, it will work for all window `scroll`,`load` and `resize`.

```
$(window).on('scroll load resize', function () {
    alert("TEST");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure because load happened before you created the listener. Think about it:

`$(window).load(function(){` When the window is loaded, do the next step:

`$(window).on('scroll load resize', function () {` creates a listener on scroll, load, and resize. Well the window already loaded so it's never going to load again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).on('scroll load resize', function () {
        alert("TEST");
    });
});
```

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3520780/when-is-window-onload-fired the window is loaded after the DOM so to keep your exact code just use the DOM ready from jQuery and it'll work, but @nikhil has an answer too. Not sure if there is an actual difference between mine and his and if any blocking occurs with his vs mine or anything. Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try

```
$(window).on('load',function()
```

But i think its the same

Answer (score 0):

You just need this code:

```
$(window).on('scroll load resize', function () {
alert("TEST");
});
```

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/af2kgoxu/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use $( document ).ready() method, and it will run whenever your DOM (Document Object Model) is ready for running javascript.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        alert("TEST");
    });
```