# Running Javascript at the end of page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to request a page in Ajax and a normal GET request. My basic layout is like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    //css file
  </head>

 **************
  <body>

  <script> </script> // this script needs to be loaded at the end of the page load in both GET and AJAX

  </body>

 *****************
  //js files (jQuery)

</html>
```

**THE area in * is loaded by ajax**

If I make a GET request, I get the complete page. And if I make an Ajax request, I get only the body part (no jQuery).

Now, the body tag contains a script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    $.getJSON("/loc", function (data) {
      // .......
    });
  };
</script>
```

This code runs fine when I make a GET request. This script gets executed after the page loads. But when I make an Ajax request, the script doesn't execute, because the page is already loaded.

So I tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("/loc", function (data) {
      .....
    });
  });
</script>
```

Now this works fine with Ajax, but doesn't work with a GET request, because jQuery is at the end of the page.

script tag is inside the body tag and the jquery is after the body tag, so if i move it after the jQuery. So I need to make 2 designs for my page: 1 for my Ajax request and 1 for my GET request. If not in Ajax I will end up loading the jQuery script twice.

So my question is can I have a single script that runs for both Ajax and GET requests?

Comment: *this works fine with ajax but doesn't work with GET request* that sentence makes no sense. AJAX and GET are seperate things, it either works or it doesn't. There's no way it works in some scenarios but not others.

Comment: Move your script tag into the head.

Comment: actually i am using laravel template so base template is like i have updated it above the if the request is ajax then i return the body else full  page but there i need to update some data after page loads

Comment: its body that changes for each page rest of it remains same so in home page i need to load data from i url no matter it is ajax or GET

Comment: hope this make sense

Comment: after body content is loaded call `eval(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML);` but be sure to call this after the contents are loaded.

Comment: content is loading correctly its just i want to execute a script a script at the end without ` window.onload = function () {` because it doesn't exceuted if body is loaded already for ajax

Comment: what I mean to say is you are "dynamically" loading the script inside body tag so the scripts doesn't execute. to execute the script inside body tag try calling eval function on that particular script

Comment: nope it doesn't do any thing

Answer (score 2):

> now this works fine with ajax but doesn't work with GET request
>   because jquery is at the end of the page

put all your scripts(and script tags) after jquery and everything should work fine.

Comment: it is inside the body tag ans script is after the body tag so i have move it after the jquery so i need to make 2 design of my page 1 for my ajax request and 1 for my GET if not the in Ajax i will end up loading jquery script twice

Comment: Why are you loading jquery in your ajax request? Don't do this

Comment: Yeah don't do that either

Comment: and jquery is after the body tag closed

Comment: take a look now

Comment: just try to use your code without onload event or use another one :) 
Or if you still want to use your approach  handle window onload event
like here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520800/3059277

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not clear but to try and point you in the right direction.

Ok your fundermental issue here is:

> this script needs to be loaded at the end of the page load in both GET
>   and AJAX

You've not given details what this script is or why it must be loaded but I'm going to say, that **it does not need to get loaded**.

When you load the page, the script gets loaded. When you load the ajax, you don't need to reload the script because it's already loaded! If you need to invoke something in the script, that's a different matter, simply call the relevant method(s) but **do not re-load the script**. It's there already leave it alone.

> I make a GET request, I get the complete page.

Again, don't do this. That's not how AJAX is supposed to work. Load only the secion of the page that you want to by dynamic:

```
<html>
  <head>
    //css file
  </head>
  <body>

  <script> </script> // this script needs to be loaded at the end of the page load in both GET and AJAX
  //NO IT DOESN'T!


  <div>
       **DYNAMIC section load this and only this**
  </div>
  </body>

  //you don't need to load JQUERY again. It's already loaded just use it.
  //js files (jQuery)

</html>
```

> fine with Ajax, but doesn't work with a GET request,

It sounds like your trying to turn a simple link into an AJAX request. Which is fine but you can't simply replace a link with `getJSON` and expect it to just work. It's more complicated than that. Basically your a long way off where you need to be here. Spend some more time learning AJAX and async loading of pages. It's not as simple as dropping a few javascript funcitons into the page and viola it's all a single page app.

Comment: ok now in your html design let's say this is your template and complete page remain same except that div tag the content inside it changes for each page let say there are two pages home and setting d there is a menu in header of a page(definitely it isn't inside the div lets say just after body) Now when user is on settings page he click home from the menu so i don't want to load the complete page i will load the content of a home page i.e., div content and replace settings div with the help of ajax and in home i need to load all post which i am not sending it in div i am loading post

Comment: i am loading post with another get script because post data is json but when user reloads the home page so i needs to send him complete page including the header and footer and when page loaded then i need to  load my post

Comment: ok then what will be your approach to solve this type of design