# jQuery .css("left") returns "auto" instead of actual value in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css

I have div element with left and top defined, **without absolute position**, and I want to read the left and top values using jQuery.

Using `$("#MyId").css("left")` gave the expected result in IE browser (IE8) but in Chrome it returned "auto" instead, although the values are explicitly written in the element style.

Here is the test case:
http://jsfiddle.net/qCDkb/2/

Note the difference between IE and Chrome.

Also, this is working well in jQuery 1.4.2 and "failing" in jQuery 1.4.3 and above.

Any insights are welcome. :-)

Comment: It stands to reason that returning `auto` is the correct behaviour, as `position: static` doesn't listen to the `left` attribute.

Comment: As verified here, notice the position is now 150px to the left.  http://jsfiddle.net/qCDkb/3/ Position: relative added to the css.

Comment: @Pekka - I don't want the actual position, for this I can use .position().left - I'm after the value defined in the CSS for that element..

Comment: Seems like a misuse of css.  You should use data() for this. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

Comment: @Gazler - I don't want to actually position the element 150 pixels to the left. I want those values there only as "flag" for using later. Probably the wrong approach.. :/

Comment: @Shadow in that case, you should be able to get that using `$("#MyId")[0].style.left` but `data()` might be an even better idea as @Gazler suggessts

Comment: @Pekka good point, but ( still can't understand why jQuery is failing to read this value in Chrome and succeeds in IE.

Comment: @Shadow yeah. I added what I know (or think) as an answer, maybe it helps

Comment: Also you should check your css. If you gave the element "right" property chrome and IE does not allow you to change the "left" property with jquery.

Comment: @Serdar no, you are not correct. See [this live example](http://jsfiddle.net/JsYJm/) to prove you wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, setting `left` to `auto` for a `position: static` sounds somehow right, seeing as `left` has no meaning in the context.

As to why Chrome and IE return different values: `.css()` provides a unified gateway to the browsers' computed style functions, but it doesn't unify the way the browsers actually compute the style. It's not uncommon for browsers to decide such edge cases differently.

As to why jQuery 1.4.2 and 1.4.3 do this differently, I do not know for sure, but there's this in [1.4.3's release notes](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/):

> Nearly the entire CSS module has been rewritten focusing entirely on extensibility. You can now write custom CSS plugins that extend the functionality provided by .css() and .animate().

Comment: Thanks, looks like the best explanation I can get. :-)

Comment: You need to hide the element before reading the property. Check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20733569/607874

Answer (score 15):

Try `$("your selector").position().top;`

Comment: You can see this yourself [in the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCDkb/237/). Not working, always returning 0 as it returns the actual position while I want to read the value I have defined inline for the element.

Comment: Worked for me in Chrome and FF.

Comment: Note the "rendering" sequence comes into play here as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready

Answer (score 13):

It is strange behavior for jQuery. But you can use native javascript methods to get css values:

```
$("#Panel1")[0].style.left
```

This expression will return corresponding css property.

Comment: This only works for inline CSS. The correct way is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/20733569/607874

Answer (score 0):

add

```
position: absolute;
```

or

```
position: relative;
```

to the element you use left on

Comment: I know, the whole point is the element can't have this. (that's why "without absolute position" is in bold in the question)

Comment: hehe, apparently not bold enough. My bad

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I ran into this same problem and thought I would suggest a couple of solutions. It seems that this problem is not specific to Chrome, as I was able to reproduce in Firefox as well.

I was able to solve this one of two ways. Either place you CSS styles in the same file as your HTML, instead of using a separate CSS file. OR, call the function inside of window.onload. Looks like the values are not available to the browser until everything has loaded, IF the styles are in an external style sheet.

Hope this is helpful.