# How to check if top, right, bottom, left of element is auto in firefox

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

On other browsers $(element).css('top') will return auto, but in firefox it return a specific value. How to find out if top, right, bottom, left is auto or a specific value on firefox?

Comment: Cannot reproduce: `$('body').css('top')` returns `"auto"` for me in Firefox 15.0.1 (on Stack Overflow, which is using jQuery 1.7.1).

Comment: You didn't ready my question carefully...

Comment: Related: [***jquery $('selector').css('top') returns different values for IE, firefox and Chrome***](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891824/jquery-selector-csstop-returns-different-values-for-ie-firefox-and-chr)

Comment: This because he is not set position: absolute, if position = absolute, the results is the same on all browser, except the firefox

Comment: @StoneHeart Your question states that `$(element).css('top')` returns "auto" on other browsers, but a *specific value in Firefox*. I tried one snippet to confirm your observation, which contradicted your statement. Can you provide a test case which proves your point (http://jsfiddle.net/ for example)?

Comment: @RobW: Sorry, I misunderstood, I managed to make it work on firefox http://jsfiddle.net/rerefreelancer/h69UF/7/

Answer (score 3):

Here is tricky way to check if top, right, bottom, left is auto or a specific value on firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/rerefreelancer/h69UF/7/

Comment: Nice, maybe you can include the full code in your answer for future reference?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a way without jQuery will do the work for you?

document.getElement...(...).style.top

In addition maybe http://api.jquery.com/category/offset/ will help you (although it doesn't fit your question).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your element is DIV then

```
<div id="check123" style="top: auto;">
       test
</div>

<script>
    alert($('#check123').css('top'));
</script>
```

same as you can check left, right, bottom.