# jQuery if statement breaks my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

This is my code:

```
$("#header").touchwipe({
//  if($('#cont-wide').css('left') == '-100%' ){
         wipeLeft: function() { 

                $('#cont-wide').animate({
                        left: '-201%'
                }, 500 );
                $('#nav-filters').fadeOut(200);
                $('#nav-map-l').delay(300).fadeIn(200);

                $('#one .col-inner').delay(500).hide(0);

                $('#three .col-inner').css('display','block');

                setTimeout(function() { 
                window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 
                100);
            },
         wipeRight: function() { 

                $('#cont-wide').animate({
                        left: '1%'
                }, 500 );
                $('#nav-filters').fadeOut(200);
                $('#nav-map-r').delay(300).fadeIn(200);

                $('#one .col-inner').css('display','block');

                setTimeout(function() { 
                window.scrollTo(0, 1) }, 
                100);

            },
         min_move_x: 50,
         min_move_y: 50,
         preventDefaultEvents: false
//  }   
});
```

As it currently is it works fine. However when I remove the comments to add the conditional statement, the code and all my other JavaScript stops working. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with that? I'm pretty sure the css function returns the value in pixels not percentages so you'd have to calculate it

Comment: hey probably your comparison is wrong $('#cont-wide').css('left') == '-100%' ? are you expecting $('#cont-wide').css('left') to return string equivalent of '-100%' which seems wrong to me. hope it helps? or you can jsfiddle it and I can help you out, cheers!

Comment: You can't just shove in an `if` statement in the middle of a statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot put the `if` statement there ...

you could do this :

```
 wipeLeft: function() { 
      if($('#cont-wide').css('left') == '-100%' ){
         // the rest
      }
 },
 wipeRight: function() { 
      if($('#cont-wide').css('left') == '-100%' ){
         // the rest
      }
 }
```

Note - the `css` function my not produce the result you are expecting : http://jsfiddle.net/VccAn/ using a value of `10%` for `left` in my example returns `auto` on Chrome ! See this question / answer for discussions related to this problem : [jQuery .css("left") returns "auto" instead of actual value in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278148/jquery-cssleft-returns-auto-instead-of-actual-value-in-chrome)

Answer (score 5):

You can't just shove in an `if` statement in the middle of a statement.

The best solution would be creating your options object before calling `touchwipe()`:

```
var options = {};
if($('#cont-wide').css('left') == '-100%') {
    options.wipeLeft = function() {

    };

    options.wipeRight = function() {

    };
}

$("#header").touchwipe(options);
```

Note that the `if` condition is only evaluated once. If you want it to be evaluated on every event, [@ManseUK's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9757497/298479) is the way to go.

Comment: Depends on what he needs though

Comment: I dont think the `css('left')` function returns what the OP expects either way !