# jQuery.css(): Firefox don't return 'auto' values

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

I'm setting top or bottom and left or right values to a few elements. When i'm trying to access this values with Firefox (16.0.2), i get a wrong value for `top` (a specific value instead of `auto`)

**CSS**

```
div {
    bottom:200px;
    left:0px;
    top:auto;
    right:auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    var top = $('div').css('top');
    alert(top);
});​
```

You can try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/UEyxD/2/ (works well in Chrome/Safari)

Any ideas how to prevent this? I want to get

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: The only way to get the original value i Firefox is to use inline CSS on the element instead, otherwise the calculated value will be returned.

Comment: @Slevin, take a look at my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is down to the browser and how it interprets the styles, it is somewhat out of your control. However, with particular CSS and jQuery workarounds you should be able to get around it. For instance, if you do not need to the item to be positioned absolutely then you could remove this, or change it to `position:static;`

Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278148/jquery-cssleft-returns-auto-instead-of-actual-value-in-chrome).

> As to why Chrome and IE return different values: .css() provides a
>   unified gateway to the browsers' computed style functions, but it
>   doesn't unify the way the browsers actually compute the style. It's
>   not uncommon for browsers to decide such edge cases differently.

Comment: This problem can be solved, if you read the css property while the element is hidden. This way the browser will not return computed value. See my answer.

Answer (score 8):

I also had this annoying problem.

Some browsers return the computed position if the element is visible at the moment. The trick is to hide it, read the css and then make it visible again (if was not already hidden).

I wrote a convenient function that takes care of this and will return `auto` in Firefox.

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/UEyxD/19/)

```
var getCss = function($elem, prop) {
        var wasVisible = $elem.css('display') !== 'none';
        try {
            return $elem.hide().css(prop);
        } finally {
            if (wasVisible) $elem.show();
        }
    };


alert( getCss($('div'), 'top') );
```

The `finally` is just to bring visibility back to the element, just before the function returns.

You should use this function only for situations where you expect `auto` to be returned.

Comment: Although I don't like the use of try/finally in this way, the actually background info helped me with the problem

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this. It's like my car has no doors while visible and when it gets invisible, doors potato-appear.

Answer (score 6):

You Can Get integer Value of top when you set 'auto' with below code:

```
$(function(){
    var top = $('div').offset().top;
    alert(top);
});​
```

- offset Return Position Value When you Set To Auto

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position` style and you will get `auto` instead of computed value.

```
div {
    top: auto;
    bottom:20px;    
    right:20px;
    left:0px;
}
```

you can test it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UEyxD/16/).

Comment: Maybe he needs the `div` to be positioned!