# Can't get margin value in Firefox and Safari

Tags: css, firefox, safari

**ANSWER UPDATED**

form my research to get **AUTO** margin-top in all browser I'm use this code

```
var bookContainer   = $('#book-container');

bookContainer.offset().top
```

---

I don't know what wrong with Firefox and Safari

It alert 0px which not correct but Chrome and IE can perform Correct

with this same code. I want to ask do you know what happen or somethings??

**JS**

```
var bookContainer   = $('#book-container');

alert(bookContainer.css('margin-top'))
```

**CSS**

```
#book-container{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 830px;
    max-height: 520px;

    /*max-width: 748px;*/
    /*max-height: 469px;*/
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery.css(): Firefox don't return 'auto' values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455931/jquery-css-firefox-dont-return-auto-values)

Comment: you set margin as auto then how calculate the margin-top.

Comment: @gowtham I have updated my answer in the question, Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

try this it worked for me

```
var leftMarginValue= $('.container').offset().left;
```

Since you are using margin auto for a div. you will get similar margin on the both side of element.