# Can't get css("left") of Stack Exchange help drop down - returns auto, wanted in px

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to get `left` property of Stack Exchange help drop down which has class `.help-dialog`, but it always returns `auto`, and I'd like to see it in px.

To avoid complicated explanations, just execute this in your address bar after any SE site is loaded:

```
javascript:alert($(".help-dialog").css("left"))
```

You'll get `auto` in the alert. How to solve it?

<sup>I have already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4278148/jquery-cssleft-returns-auto-instead-of-actual-value-in-chrome), but [second](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4278515/) and [third](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13794616) suggestions don't appear to work, other ones are inapplicable.</sup>

Comment: What does `$` refer to? jQuery? if so, you should tag it in the question as well

Comment: If you inspect and see on page load the help-dialog is after the link `help` and when clicked its put into a div called topbar with `left` calculated so you wont get a value on load. What you can do is get the left value of the link `help`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns `auto` because the element is not visible after page load, see:

```
$('.help-dialog').is(':visible')
```

The help menu is initialized on click and that's when the `left` attribute is set. Click on it after page load and try again:

```
$('.help-dialog').css('left'))
```

**To solve this, use:**

```
$('a.js-help-button').click();
var left=$('.help-dialog').css('left');
$('a.js-help-button').click();
alert(left);
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need *two* click events?

Comment: @Bram So as not to leave the dialog expanded. Because that was not my aim - to expand the dialog, so we hide it after getting data.

Answer (score 1):

This returns 840.5 on my screen at https://meta.stackexchange.com/.

```
javascript:$('.help-dialog').show();var left=$(".help-dialog").offset().left;$('.help-dialog').hide(); alert(left)
```

Comment: Do you get a different value, or do you still get "auto"?  What stackexchange site are you viewing?

Comment: I am viewing directly on this page, getting 0.

Comment: My bad, I had manually set it to visible first.  Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try position method instead of css method,

```
$('a.js-help-button').click();
$(".help-dialog").position();
```

.help-dialog is hidden, try to make it visible by clicking on it. and then get its position . You will get its top and left in px

Comment: Good answer but the OP is not interested in genuine answers but in gaming the system and giving preferential treatment to certain accounts +1.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try this?

```
$('.help-dialog')[0].offsetLeft;
```

Comment: @nicael How come? It returns 0 not `auto`

Comment: While it is around 700. Differs for different screen sizes, but it is not 0.