# Can I prevent jQuery UI from setting 'position: relative' on elements that were made draggable before being added to the DOM+

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

Reduced test case: http://jsfiddle.net/Kerrick/CETWC/

In short, I am creating a jQuery element (such as via `var el = $('<h1>Test</h1>');`), enabling jQuery UI's [draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) functionality (`el.draggable()`), and appending it to the DOM (such as via `$('body').append(el);`). Instead of using `position: absolute` as jQuery UI usually does, it puts `position: relative` into the `style` attribute of the element.

Can I prevent this and force jQuery UI to use `postion: absolute` even when enabled on an element that has yet to be appended to the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

just change its css to position while appending

```
$('<h1 class="draggable">Test</h1>')
    .draggable()
    .appendTo('#canvas').css('position','absolute');
$('<h2 class="draggable">Test 2</h2>')
    .draggable()
    .appendTo('#canvas').css('position','absolute');
```

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CETWC/6/) what you really want?

**EDIT:**

Though I couldnt figure out the root cause of the problem, these links might help you

[Link1](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4796)
[Link2](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7220)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194750/jqueryui-draggable-sets-position-relative-on-my-draggable-divs)

Comment: While overriding the `position` property after jQuery UI sets it incorrectly gives me the end goal I'm looking for, I was hoping to find the root of the problem so I didn't need to set the CSS propert via jQuery (or use `!important` in my CSS).