# Is there a way to know when external CSS inside <head> has been applied, but not to wait for images to load

Tags: javascript, onload

`$(document).ready()` [does not guarantee that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready)

`window.onload` waits for [all inline (I mean static) images](http://www.quirksmode.org/elsewhere/archives/javascript/events/onload/index.html)

`DOMContentLoaded` does not wait for external CSS

Any other solution? Have I missed anything?

It should be cross browser (at least major browsers). And of course I'm not asking about dynamicaly loaded stylesheets.

Comment: I thought CSS was applied in realtime...?

Comment: `document.styleSheets[0].onload`

Comment: The MDN gives a solution [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTML/Element/link).

Comment: My only doubt is about the existence of other solutions, as I know browsers block the rendering until head stylesheets are loaded. And I'm not 100% sure the load event may really occur before head stylesheets are loaded.

Comment: @dystroy - sounds about right, but how would one test that? javascript is useless at such an early time in the rendering, and I'm not sure the console would be much help either ?

Comment: @adeneo This might be why this question still has no answer. But your `styleSheet.onload` solution could be one. :)

Comment: @dystroy - not posting it ;) ,,, I have no idea if it works or not, but it's there in the comment for anyone who's willing to try it out ?

Comment: It should be cross browser. And dynamic stylesheets are not in the game

Comment: Could you elaborate on why .ready() doesn't fit?

Comment: @RickViscomi yes of course http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready

Comment: @Kolink: it can take ages for external styleshhet to load

Comment: @Dan Only if it's a stupidly large file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In certain conditions, the DOMContentLoaded event might be the one you are looking for:

```
 window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', func, false);
```

You will need to place the external stylesheet in the head and the external javascript in the footer, so this event will not be fired before the styles are applied, but right after.

See: http://molily.de/weblog/domcontentloaded and http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/14/how-javascript-loading-works-domcontentloaded-and-onload/ for reference.

Also, it will not work on IE<9 (of course).