# Rails: Running Javascript only after CSS loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm using Google Maps API V3 in a .js file loaded by turbolinks.

The map rendering is triggered when the `$('#google-map')` element is loaded:

```
function initGoogleMap() {
   ...
   var map = new google.maps.Map($('#google-map').get(0), mapOptions);
   ...
}

$('#google-map').ready(function() {
  initGoogleMap();
});
```

The problem is that when `initGoogleMap()` runs, it uses the width and height of `$('#google-map')` to render the map, **and at this point the width and height are 0**.

The width and height are defined in a .scss file named after the controller:

```
.map {
    height: 300px;
    width: 400px;

    #google-map {
        height: 300px;
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

I'm using rails' conventions, so in my view template there is no mention of either the .js filename or the .scss filename.

How can I make sure the script only runs after the stylesheet is loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Part 1: Page specific JS:**

Check out one possible solution to page-specific JS in the rails pipeline here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11975103/1162491

**Part 2: Running JS after CSS rules are applied:**

I'm assuming that your CSS is loaded in the `<head>` of your application layout. At the bottom of your template, [include the page-specific javascript](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/javascript_include_tag) with `javascript_include_tag` and have your javascript load when the document is ready. This should resolve your issues; however, as [this SO post shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324568/is-document-ready-also-css-ready), placing the stylesheet tags before your javascript tags may not always result in the expected behavior, since CSS is loaded async. So, as one answer in that post suggests,

```
$(window).load(function() { $('#abc')...} );
```

might consistently perform better than `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Can you please explain the connection between my question and Part 1 of your answer? Also, which of the answers there seems relevant to my question and why?

Comment: Presumably you don't want/need all of your javascript running at the very end of your document, so, place what you do need at the end in a different javascript file. I've fixed the link to go directly to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11975103/1162491

Comment: `$(window).load` seems to have solved all my problems.

Answer (score 0):

As the jquery's ready() function explains(http://api.jquery.com/ready/),

```
In cases where code relies on loaded assets (for example, if the dimensions of an image are required), the code should be placed in a handler for the load event instead.
```

so use load() method may solves your problem.

```
$('#google-map').load(function() {
  initGoogleMap();
});
```

Comment: I've tried using `load`, but now the code doesn't run at all.